# Как установить границы для position: absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать так чтобы `tooltip` не выходил за границы `content`?

```css
.page {
flex: 1;
}
.content {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.field {

}
.icon {
position: relative;
}
.icon .tooltip {
position: absolute;
top: -100%;
left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Описание <i class="icon"><div class="tooltip">Текст тултипа</div></i></label>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Описание <i class="icon"><div class="tooltip">Текст тултипа</div></i></label>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Описание <i class="icon"><div class="tooltip">Текст тултипа</div></i></label>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Описание <i class="icon"><div class="tooltip">Текст тултипа</div></i></label>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Цель в том чтобы где бы не находился `tooltip`, он автоматически отступал от краев `content`

upd.
Чтобы не выходило из этих краев
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо добавить св-во `position: relative` для родительского элемента

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  /*...*/
}

/*...*/
```

Comment: Родителем является иконка, от неё и нужно позиционировать, задать релеватив для контента тут не помогает. Но я хочу задать дополнительные ограничения для того чтобы тултип не выходил за пределы контента.

Comment: @Pichenka вы не можете хотеть чтобы не выходило за края и насильно ставить `top: -100%` вместе с `position: absolute`. Св-во `position` у родителя и дитя только помогает понять откуда начать считать, но абсолютно никак не запрещает чему-либо выходить за границы чего-то

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="tooltip">Наведи КА!
        <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip текст</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Стрелку можно сделать через псевдо класс :after

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но тут как раз тултип выходит за рамки контейнера. Задача в том чтобы он не выходил за эти рамки, на скрине отметил за какую рамку он не должен уходить.

Comment: измените left: 60%; эм... я немного не понимаю если честно. С этим кодом манипулировать тултипом можно как угодно